# VSTO for Outlook 2010 returning nothing instead of contact?

Tags: vb.net, vsto, outlook-2010

I'm trying to create a right-click menu on the Outlook 2010 contacts view which returns all phone numbers for a contact

I have put in the following XML:

```
<contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuContactItem">
  <button id="MyContextMenuContactItem"
      imageMso="AutoDial"
      label="Click to dial"
      onAction="OnMyButtonClick"/>
</contextMenu>
```

And this correctly displays the right click item on the contacts list when I right click. I have so far added the following code to the onAction:

```
Public Sub OnMyButtonClick(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
    Dim card As Office.IMsoContactCard = TryCast(control.Context, Office.IMsoContactCard)
    If card Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Nothing")
    Else
        MsgBox("We have a card")
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is here - and I always get nothing. I need to get 'Business Phone' for example ideally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some C# code that accesses the ContactItem object you've selected in the Contacts Folder.  I realize yours is VB, but since they'll both have access to the same object model, it should be just a matter of changing the syntax.

```
public void OnMyButtonClick(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{ 
    if (control.Context is Outlook.Selection)
    {
        Outlook.Selection selected = control.Context as Outlook.Selection;

        var x = selected.GetEnumerator();
        x.MoveNext();
        if (x.Current is Outlook.ContactItem)
        {
            Outlook.ContactItem card = x.Current as Outlook.ContactItem;
            Debug.Print(card.FirstName + "'s phone number: " + card.BusinessTelephoneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For VB:
    Dim selected As Outlook.Selection = TryCast(control.Context, Outlook.Selection)
    Dim x As System.Collections.IEnumerator = selected.GetEnumerator
    x.MoveNext()
    Dim card As Outlook.ContactItem = TryCast(x.Current, Outlook.ContactItem)
    MsgBox(card.FirstName)